# Authentication in CakePhp 3

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I think I got a mistake in the Authorization of my App. I want only to allow to add Pages by users with an admin role.  But I can access the add function with no problem. So here is what I did.

**AppController**

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Moves',
            'action' => 'view'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);

 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{

    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display', 'english', 'italian', 'german']);
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'home');
    $this->loadModel('Menus');


    $main_de = $this->Menus->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Menus.action' => 'main_de')
    ));
    $this->set('main_de', $main_de);

    $main_us = $this->Menus->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Menus.action' => 'main_us')
    ));
    $this->set('main_us', $main_us);

}

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

**Pages**

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        // All registered users can add articles
        if ($this->request->action === 'add') {
            return false;
        }

        // The owner of an article can edit and delete it
        if (in_array($this->request->action, ['edit', 'delete'])) {
            $articleId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
            if ($this->Articles->isOwnedBy($articleId, $user['id'])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding **'authorize' => 'Controller'**, to the Auth Array

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Moves',
            'action' => 'view'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ],
        //  **'authorize' => 'Controller',**

]);
```

Comment: Well done for answering your own question but please _answer_ the question, don't just dump (badly formatted, and the same as the question) code.